# Solr updates are very slow

Tags: lucene, solr

I am seeing extremely slow Solr updates in my database. The database only has 900 documents.  We use autocommit with the following settings, and once in a while autocommit is taking long time blocking updates:

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```

What in the world can be happening for 74 seconds with 900 documents.

Ideas?

Here is the log snippet:

Oct 18, 2010 11:52:46 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={} status=0 **QTime=59569** 
Oct 18, 2010 11:52:46 AM org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter getDirectory

Oct 18, 2010 11:53:21 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={} status=0 **QTime=33586** 
Oct 18, 2010 11:53:21 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:40 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={} status=0 **QTime=76098** 
Oct 18, 2010 11:54:41 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit

And the commit log:

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:00 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit

INFO: start commit(optimize=false,waitFlush=true,waitSearcher=true)

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:00 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher

INFO: Opening Searcher@29b003 main

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:00 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit

INFO: end_commit_flush

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:00 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm

INFO: autowarming Searcher@29b003 main from Searcher@718c93 main
        filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=512,evictions=0,size=257,warmupTime=19294,cumulative_lookups=3330661,cumulative_hits=12
5437,cumulative_hitratio=0.03,cumulative_inserts=3207537,cumulative_evictions=3184094}

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:20 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm

INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@29b003 main
        filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=256,evictions=0,size=256,warmupTime=19739,cumulative_lookups=3330661,cumulative_hits=12
5437,cumulative_hitratio=0.03,cumulative_inserts=3207537,cumulative_evictions=3184094}

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:20 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm

INFO: autowarming Searcher@29b003 main from Searcher@718c93 main
        queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=256,evictions=0,size=256,warmupTime=18604,cumulative_lookups=3084,cumulative_hits=
996,cumulative_hitratio=0.32,cumulative_inserts=2313,cumulative_evictions=0}

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:40 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm

INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@29b003 main
        queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=256,evictions=0,size=256,warmupTime=19925,cumulative_lookups=3084,cumulative_hits=
996,cumulative_hitratio=0.32,cumulative_inserts=2313,cumulative_evictions=0}

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:40 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm

INFO: autowarming Searcher@29b003 main from Searcher@718c93 main
        documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=41846,cumulative_hits=33712,cumu
lative_hitratio=0.80,cumulative_inserts=8134,cumulative_evictions=0}

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:40 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm

INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@29b003 main
        documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=41846,cumulative_hits=33712,cumu
lative_hitratio=0.80,cumulative_inserts=8134,cumulative_evictions=0}

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:40 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher

INFO: [] Registered new searcher Searcher@29b003 main

Oct 18, 2010 11:54:40 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher close

Comment: Depends on what kind of analysis Solr has to do... can you post your schema.xml?

Comment: It is nothing special - a dozen fields per document. 5 facets.

Comment: What is interesting that there is large warm up time of one of the searchers, why would that be?

Answer (score 8):

With `<maxTime>1000</maxTime>`, you will have a commit at each second. Each time Solr does a commit, there is a couple of things that happens: the index searcher is closed and reopened, the caches are warmed with the old caches and some queries might be launch automatically (look at 'newSearcher' settings in your solrconfig). At some point, you might have overlapping commit. Solr will be usually real slow if this happen.

So ask yourself if you really need to have a commit at each second. If yes, it is probably better to remove all queries from the 'newSearcher', since committing that frequently renders them useless.

Comment: I assumed that the data is not available for searching before you commit. So the logic was to apply small amount of changes asynchronously pretty often. Secondly, I think DirectUpdateHandler2 seem to handle update requests (including commits) serially - w/o overlap.

Comment: why that? "logic was to apply small amount of changes asynchronously pretty often" -> this is real time and definitely not necessary in normal cases. for you second question: the problem is that indexing takes a while + warming up queries (if cachesize != 0) => you'll get a lot of updaters => reach the maximum of thos updaters very quickly => performance bottleneck! simply try setting 1000 to 60000

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Alternatively, you can do manual commits (SolrServer.commit()) from the code that does the updates. Then no automatic commits are needed.